# Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only

Tags: discussion, images, ssl

This is a cross post [from mSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images), but affecting the whole network. `1.` is already enabled network wide, `2.` and `3.` will be enabled shortly on mSE and another SE community (main site + meta) of our choosing for the first round of site-wide HTTPS testing. Read the [full master plan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345012/155005)!

As requested by [@patrick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291948/156631), lets go kill dead images. We don't have on-demand review queues, and editing a list of posts works OK for small batches<sup>1</sup>, let's take crowdcrafting.org / pybossa for a spin. So, without further ado:

[**I need a bosse**](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/)<sup>2</sup>

- 2017-03-07 (meta.)security.SE processed, (only) 28 tasks added to ^^
- 2017-03-08 serverfault, superuser and their metas processed, 1069 tasks
- 2017-03-09 25 main SE sites processed, 7911 (somebody call the police) tasks
- 2017-03-09 deleted mSE posts have been removed from the crowdsourcing queue
- 2017-03-10 rest of the public SE sites done, 6225 tasks for the queue
- 2017-03-11 fixed 2 URLs on askubuntu.com which just received https support, but affected [~2k posts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35974525#35974525)
- child metas for .SE sites will be processed after the meta move

---

In the next 6-8 weeks, we'll be rolling out some changes to address the mixed content issue on the first page load, namely:

1. Imgur URLs are converted from HTTP to HTTPS. This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected. This has already shipped, and all the old posts were rebaked.
2. Prevent submission of posts that contain HTTP images. Instead of the HTTP image the markdown editor will show an additional error...
   [image: additional error]
   ... with an option to bring up the image uploading tool with the URL pre-populated, so you can easily upload it to Imgur (we can't do that on your behalf, because cc-by-sa, and whatnot):
   [image: image uploaded - pre-populated with url]
3. After this is enabled, old posts that have HTTP images, accessible via HTTPS, will be edited accordingly. This will be an actual markdown change, attributed to the "URL Rewriter Bot"; posts won't be bumped. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732/timeline#history_bfdef789-8377-41a3-bd80-86425b19db12))
4. Rebake remaining posts with HTTP images, so that images linking to HTTP addresses will become links - most of those are dead anyway. This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected, but it'll remove any mixed content even when viewing old revisions.

---

<sub>[1] ... and inspired by [Let's rescue wayward resource requests! (trial run)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run)</sub>
<sub>[2] ... depending on how this works out, we might use it for other stuff too</sub>

Comment: You have an odd way of writing MSO and MSE :)

Comment: @Stijn If we're being pedantic, lowercase-m is a more proper way. Prevents confusion of Meta Stack Exchange and Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Stijn, given his name, he should write it as ms0. :P

Comment: @Undo Good thing we don't have any other sites with names that start with M or else we'd be in real trouble.

Comment: [tag:featured] please? Pretty please? 0:)

Comment: There are removed question and answer pages that are not viewable to users without enough reputation. Should such a crowd crafter click "Done" or "Skip" in such a case?

Comment: @FrenzyLi "Skip" would be better, "Done" throws it out of the queue, let me add some instructions there

Comment: @m0sa I didn't even think about this in the beginning and clicked "Done" for about about 20 cases. Is it possible to revert my actions?

Comment: @FrenzyLi don't sweat it, it takes two "Done" responses for the task to be completed

Comment: @m0sa highly likely Frenzy Li and I could have clicked Done on the same posts, since the same posts repeated quite a few times for me.

Comment: I also got feedback from another user saying that when removing dead links to pictures, do not insert placeholders like `[removed link to image]`.

Comment: i keep getting the same ones when skipping

Comment: The crowdcrafting site thing seems to have an awful lot of un-editable posts that turn out to have been migrated to MSU/MSO/whatever. There's a number of things that would bore me straight out of contributing, and getting four or five of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Glw4.png) from the `edit` button is definitely one of them.

Comment: that's totally my bad.. added another button so you can dismiss those, calls the api to see if the post is there or not, to make your life easy...

Comment: @m0sa I don't see how it makes my life easier in any way. Why is it giving me *any* deleted posts at all? I'm there to provide human input, not do a bunch of things that a computer can do by itself. Is it deleted? Good, then skip to one that isn't, don't ask me to confirm what you already know is true.

Comment: Is the image used for flair in the HTML snippet on stackexchange.com going to be updated? I went to update my profile on Arqade, and noticed the above error since currently the flair snippet uses HTTP for the image (changing it to HTTPS fixed it).

Comment: This post is locked and I can't edit or flag it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9238

Comment: Can someone explain the "Why" behind change, for those of us who might be curious (and are as not as tech savvy)?

Comment: @m0sa : remember http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281385/242800 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69171/242800.

Comment: @Skooba we haz https!

Comment: @DanielA.White have you found a working image?

Comment: Could be problematic when linking images that are on HTTP-only sites without any license to copy and republish - might we end up encouraging infringement as a side effect?  (And yes, I'm one of the people who moans when I find the alt text instead of an image when it's avoidable).

Comment: @TobySpeight that's why we don't do it automatically, and the link explicitly says "**upload** to imgur". The fact that the HTTP URL is copied into the uploader, is merely a convenience, so that as a user, you don't have to go search for the URL, copy, and paste it manually.

Comment: Good to hear that you're already considering that.  :-)

Comment: *“so you can easily upload it to Imgur (we can't do that on your behalf, because cc-by-sa, and whatnot)”* – If that’s an actual issue, maybe you should highlight that a bit more prominently in the upload dialog?

Comment: Has this run on Ask Ubuntu yet? I see this example: https://askubuntu.com/posts/50387/revisions so I assume that it has?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS yes, it ran yesterday (2017-03-09)

Comment: Can I ask you to rerun it on Ask Ubuntu? We had a bunch of images hosted on our own server that didn't support HTTPS yet. Support was added literally hours after you run it (our bad) and now we have hundreds of these to update. Feel free to pop into AU chat if you have any questions: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Is there a recommended way to find posts with images that've been turned into links on a specific site? (I see the crowdsourcing thing, but I'd kind of like to work on the site I moderate, and rope in others there if possible.) I know there *were* SEDE queries that worked, but they don't seem to now - everything I know of was looking for `<img src="http://` in Post.Body and that doesn't seem to match anymore.

Comment: Okay, so I tried using the export here http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/tasks/export and I'm a little concerned the input data may not all be correct. It starts out sane: `"info" : { "BaseHostAddress" : "meta.stackexchange.com", "PostId" : "150",` ... but then looking for entries for cooking, I find: `"info" : { "askubuntu.com" : "cooking.stackexchange.com", ` ... `"149" : "1561"`

Comment: The API is returning the same ([e.g.](http://crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667&last_id=1710643)), looks like all MSE then security.se entries are fine then everything else is borked.. any idea what's going on there @m0sa ?

Comment: ugh, looks like I've imported a CSV without headers and it took the first row's values as column names... I've created a merged, cleaned up [CSV file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/m0sa/2b1273c3ae4b482bbd6649e40fa1b5ad/raw/8137053a5aaf084af702052870e5106d65a6ae7a/items-revised.csv), but unfortunately the pybossa API [dosen't have](https://github.com/Scifabric/pbs/blob/6cd139a8ff16ef84e87c3e5a1dc9a0fd8128b454/helpers.py#L206) a bulk delete endpoint... So, instead, I made the UI great again, by forcing it to support the alt-columns...

Comment: The CrowdCrafting thing seems ineffective. I've looked at 30 posts that are shown on the site and all of them have already been fixed. I'm giving up.

Comment: Can the flair images be fixed with an HTML rebake? We've got a fair number of moderator-related posts that aren't working right now. (I've been [fixing them by hand](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3114/revisions), but that's maybe not the best use of my time. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson yes, they will be.. we didn't fix (rebake/rewrite) links to non-meta sites yet. we will do so shortly, though.

Comment: Has there been a recent change in this policy? Non-https images are now being displayed; see for example [Is there a way to get the closed form approximate result of $\int\_ 0^a\frac {e^{-x - \frac {1} {x}}} {x}\, dx$](//mathoverflow.net/a/256376).

Answer (score 35):

Nice work on finally bringing HTTPS support in!

I want to note something on point 4 (emphasis mine):

> Rebake remaining posts with HTTP images, so that images linking to HTTP addresses will become links - **most of those are dead anyway**.

If most of those links are dead anyway, why not go through the hassle once and check if they are actually dead or not. If they are, just remove them! Why would we need to rely on the community to fix one by one if we can do this automated at once?

---

It seems automating this is difficult, so m0sa set up a [crowd sourcing project](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/) to let us do the work manually. Please contribute if you can! About 2500 posts to go...

Comment: we do check, note point `3.` - **old posts that have HTTP images, accessible via HTTPS, will be edited accordingly**, `4.` is just cleaning up what's left

Comment: But with 4 you say you convert the non-HTTPS images to links, not remove them.

Comment: we can't just remove them

Comment: Oh yes you can :) . Why not?

Comment: they have an alt text or something describing what is mean to be there

Comment: Then replace then with some useful text, the alt, put them in review or something else.

Comment: we do put the alt text in the link text

Comment: But why keep the link if the image is dead?

Comment: would you rather dig through revision history than have it right there?

Comment: Well, generally there is no use in a dead link, so we edit them out. If you have to test if an image supports HTTPS, and if that fails also checks if there is still a HTTP image, and that fails too, you could just remove it entirely. Maybe leaving a boilerplate text like the ALT in place.

Comment: if we edit it out, the next person editing the post won't get the HTTPS only images warning, which *might* prod them into finding a replacement image

Comment: That is true, but will it ever come so far? I would usually just remove the dead link. Usually there is no way to get it back anyway, unless you knew what was there before.

Comment: [Related analysis of dead links of SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them)  (disclaimer...it's my post)

Comment: @PatrickHofman see update, TL;DR -> http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/

Comment: @PatrickHofman with the information, somebody who cares can find a different image or dig through the Wayback Machine to get it.  Without the information, and (as in most cases) without meaningful alt text or sufficient description in the post body, we've got no idea.

Comment: Is it possible to notify the user that added the image that it can't be converted to https? If _I_ added one, I may be able to find a replacement. Also, is there a way to check if I have ever added one in the first place (to the Bat-Mob... ehr, SEDE!)

Comment: Sure it is, but it would mean some users would have a dozen notifications in their inbox, with almost certainly no result. @SQB

Comment: @m0sa: The CC project also shows deleted posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3194.

Comment: It's a one off process, so they get processed as well, in case they ever get undeleted... But I guess in that case we're OK with a broken link? You're right though, I could've skipped the deleted ones when adding them to the queue. I'm totally planing to reuse the queue for other sites as well, so I'll exclude deleted posts next time

Comment: Dead images can be fixed by providing a working URL, if it's clear what was supposed to be there.

Comment: @Raphael of course, but many times there's no such URL, and searching for similar image will just take tons of time better spent on other things.

Comment: @m0sa Can you make a new list for us containing only visible posts? We are now spending tons of time on deleted posts. I haven't actually seen a visible post in the queue yet.

Comment: After 10 deleted posts, I stopped running through the system. Better to exclude them if you do it again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The dead link can often be found using the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), or possibly cached by Google.

Comment: @m0sa – Why does this have to be externally crowdsourced?  Why not add extra JS into SE sites that ping a central server when an image fails to load, then after a minimum threshold of pings from unique ~CIDR/24s, crawl it yourself?  That'd at least identify the broken images.  I assume most of them can be formulaically corrected.  The rest would be ranked by popularity to prioritize human vetting.

Comment: @AdamKatz not really, since IMHO the steps listed above already get rid of mixed content... the crowdsourcing thing is just an afterthought, a replacement for editing lists of post ids in a markdown post (see footnote 1). It's basically my attempt of putting lipstick on a pig. Anyone from the community could've done it, even on SO, since the lists of changed post IDs are public there as well. So I apologize if the execution isn't ideal, but it's much better than what we did till now IMO.

Comment: Who came up with "most HTTP images are dead"? Was that actually based on a check, or just an assumption? All of my older images are hosted on my domain because SE didn't have imgur support back then, and I don't have SSL configured, but all the images work just fine over HTTP. I've been seeing people manually edit my old posts to upload the images to imgur; is that not automatable?

Comment: Yes, it is, but probably could end up in tons of legal problems if SE edits the images themselves. @MichaelMrozek I don't know if, and so why, was responsible for saying HTTP images are dead. Not sure how to read that too.

Answer (score 6):

Please make it so that [protocol relative URLs](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) (i.e. `//foo.bar/fum.png`) will still be possible (you write that you will *require* `https:`) and are left alone.

Comment: Some images can only be served over HTTP, others only over HTTPS. Using a protocol relative URL might break things.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think Martin is (also?) referring to posts that currently have images with a protocol-relative URL In them. Since these are presumably already available over HTTPS, it would make sense to leave this kind of URI alone (as in: don't convert them to a link) as they'd get loaded over HTTPS if the embedding page is also loaded over HTTPS, anyway.

Comment: I could agree with that, although it is little work to update them too.

Comment: @user2428118: Indeed. Also intra-stackexchange links in comments without the schema are shorter, which enables us to write longer comments. :-)

Comment: There is absolutely no sense in using protocol-relative URLs anymore. All clients support (or should) https, and TLS is not slow anymore. The only reason protocol-relative URLs were useful was to speed up load times when the page was loaded over http anyways. Now it's no use to use this hack syntax to explicitly downgrade the security of the asset being linked to (image) if it can be served over https. Plus it breaks the filesystem scheme. https://joonas.fi/2016/12/27/stop-using-protocol-relative-urls/

Comment: @MartinSchröder Did you even read the link in your answer? *Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance concerns, **this technique is now an anti-pattern**. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then **always** use the `https://` asset.*

Answer (score 4):

Is anyone else having problems with imageshack images? They keep coming back with failures.

Comment: That's pretty stock for Imageshack, they are very fond of deleting vaguely old images as soon as they get an excuse. (One of the reasons we're so insistent on imgur hosting these days, in fact.)

Comment: Do you have the user script installed mentioned halfway this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising/264155#264155

Comment: Do know that I have gone over all imageshack images on MSE a couple of weeks ago and rescued what was still available.

Answer (score 3):

I've written the following snippet (also posted at [Help us fix broken images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291976/307988)) to filter and return the [Crowdcrafting tasks](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/) by site.

It currently returns up to 100 tasks (the maximum [the API](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/api.html) allows). It looks like a lot of sites have fewer affected posts than that, there's no instant way to get further posts for the ones that do though. It is possible to paginate results through the API (see the last note [here](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/api.html#order-by)), so maybe I'll look at adding that later.

I've included links to the SE post (both view and edit links) *and* the Crowdcrafting task page so that you can hit "Done" on the task, which should eventually get you more tasks (it takes 2 "Done"s to remove the post from the queue I believe).

Just pick a site, hit "Get Tasks" and work through the links...

```js
function getget(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    callback(response);
  });
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

function loadSites() {
  var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=300&filter=!*L6Sij27hkbD7Gso';
  getget(url, listSites);
}

function listSites(sites) {
  var goBtn = document.getElementById('getTasks');
  var sitesList = document.getElementById('sites');

  for (var i = 0; i < sites.items.length; i++) {
    var siteUrl = sites.items[i].site_url.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "");
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = siteUrl;
    opt.textContent = sites.items[i].name;
    sitesList.appendChild(opt);
  }

  goBtn.innerText = 'Get Tasks';
  goBtn.disabled = false;
}

function listTasks(tasks, el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    var task = tasks[i],
      info = task.info,
      taskID = task.id,
      // borked column headers again...
      postID = info['PostId'] || info['12'] || info['149'] || info['73'] || '',
      siteName = info.BaseHostAddress || info['meta.serverfault.com'] || info['askubuntu.com'] || info['sound.stackexchange.com'] || '';

    lastID = taskID;

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = 'Post ' + postID + ':';

    var seViewLink = document.createElement('a');
    seViewLink.href = '//' + siteName + '/questions/' + postID;
    seViewLink.innerText = 'View';

    var seEditLink = document.createElement('a');
    seEditLink.href = '//' + siteName + '/posts/' + postID + '/edit';
    seEditLink.innerText = 'Edit';

    var ccLink = document.createElement('a');
    ccLink.className = 'ccLink';
    ccLink.href = '//crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/task/' + taskID;
    ccLink.innerText = 'Crowdcrafting Task ' + taskID;

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(seViewLink);
    li.appendChild(seEditLink);
    li.appendChild(ccLink);
    results.appendChild(li);
  }
}

function init() {
  var goBtn = document.getElementById('getTasks');
  goBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    results.innerHTML = '';

    var site = document.getElementById('sites').value;
    var searchUrl = '//crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667&limit=100&info=BaseHostAddress::' + site;
    getget(searchUrl, listTasks, results);

    // task columns are borked... let's run this a few times
    var searchUrl = '//crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667&limit=100&info=meta.serverfault.com::' + site;
    getget(searchUrl, listTasks, results);
    var searchUrl = '//crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667&limit=100&info=askubuntu.com::' + site;
    getget(searchUrl, listTasks, results);
    var searchUrl = '//crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667&limit=100&info=sound.stackexchange.com::' + site;
    getget(searchUrl, listTasks, results);
  });
  loadSites();
}

// go!
init();
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }
li { margin: 0; padding: .5em 0; }
span { display: inline-block; width: 6em; }
a { color: #fff; background-color: #03A7DD; border-radius: 4px; padding: .25em .5em; margin: 0 .5em 0 0; text-decoration: none; }
a.ccLink { background-color: #2B9884; }
```

```html
<label>Site: <select id="sites"></select></label>
<button id="getTasks" disabled>Loading Sites...</button>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

*Note, links in Stack Snippets don't really work... just open them in a new tab (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, <kbd>middle-click</kbd>, <kbd>right-click</kbd>+"Open in New Tab" or whatever)*

Answer (score 2):

This is nice =).

It would be nicer if someone can write a SEDE query that can find old posts that need fixing - i.e. posts with non-stack.imgur images included.

And also, while we're here, it would be nice if you guys could eliminate dependences to profile images from cdn.facebook and other trackersy domains.

Comment: http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/. (does not really work right now, stuck on deleted posts, but it should bring all posts with dead images.)

Comment: Indeed, as Shadow Wizard says. See my answer here and its [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291976/245360) about the progress.

Comment: I've been using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2009-12-01&EndDate=2017-01-01); does that help?

Comment: the [api endpoint for enumerating tasks](http://crowdcrafting.org/api/task?project_id=4667) is public, you can get the post ids from there

Comment: @Mithrandir That seems to no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

I just decided to try the crowdcrafting.org link in the question above, and [the first task I received](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/task/1708249) contained a link to [`https://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/227`](https://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/227).

Obviously, that's not going to work (unless I edit the URL or manually add a security exception for the invalid certificate), since it's still using the old meta.security hostname.  I guess that something that should be fixed?

<sup>Also, it turns out I can't handle that task anyway, since I'm 22 rep points short of having edit privileges on security.SE meta.  But that's not really something the crowdcrafting site could possibly know.</sup>

Comment: thanks, I've fixed the links, they now point to the old HTTP address, which redirects to https by default now.

Answer (score 2):

I found a bug: First task I got was http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17393 which was complaining about an img tag which was in backticks so it wasn't actually an image. This img tag doesn't need fixing, but it ended up in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say thanks for having the editor make it super easy to upload. It saves a lot of time...

I wish I wasn't rate limited on my edits because I was moving thru a lot...