# Did something change in SEDE's data?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Over on Ask Ubuntu, we have been using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/639337/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2010-12-01&EndDate=2017-04-01) to find out old posts with non-imgur images. It was working alright before this weekend, but now it's returning 0 rows. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The query is specifically looking for images (i.e.  `img` tags) that have a HTTP `src`. As stated in [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/307988), those have been nuked (silently by the Community user, without bumping posts). They were either auto-converted to HTTPS images or plain text links; neither of which will be found by that query.

SEDE is only updated weekly, on Sundays, so the query would have returned the already fixed posts until today when it was updated.

Comment: Yep, just realised that myself. Now it seems only devs can find the images to be fixed.

Comment: @muru the affected posts have all been added to [the crowd rafting project](http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/). You should be able to pull the post ids from the [API](http://crowdcrafting.org/help/api) and filter by site, I'm going to see if I can work something when I've got a bit more time later tonight.

Comment: if you can, that would be awesome. I got stuck in the "same two posts in a loop" problem that has affected others and would rather not use that site.

Comment: Yep, me too, and promptly gave up after that :) I'll let you know if I manage to come up with something

Comment: There's also a way to download full csv or json here: http://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/tasks/export

Comment: And... it does not look like all the data is good :( It starts out sane: `"info" : { "BaseHostAddress" : "meta.stackexchange.com", "PostId" : "150",` but then looking for entries for cooking, I find: `"info" : { "askubuntu.com" : "cooking.stackexchange.com", ` ... `"149" : "1561"`

Comment: @Jefromi looks like the API returns the same... not sure whats going on there :(

Comment: Yeah, I assume this is because the actual uploaded tasks are bad (maybe some kind of escaping bug), not because we're using the export/API wrong, so if people actually got to those tasks they'd be broken. I commented on the original question asking about it. For what it's worth I think the values are legit, e.g. post 1561 on cooking does have an http image link, but it makes it pretty hard to use in general, and I'm especially not sure how to use the link field.

Comment: @muru I've written a snippet to filter the crowdcrafting tasks by site, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292279/307988

Comment: @Jefromi see above

Answer (score 3):

Images are undergoing migration from http to https as part of the grand [Stack Exchange migration to https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time).

[Removing http from the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/639346/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2015-12-01&EndDate=2017-01-01) produces some results for me, although feedback suggests it's flawed somehow.

[Rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) has created [a better query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/639353/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2015-12-01&EndDate=2016-01-01) since mine seems to be missing results.

Comment: 2 results, whereas it should be in the hundreds (about 400, keeping track with the results from last weekend)

Comment: [470 results](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/639353/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2015-12-01&EndDate=2016-01-01) @muru

Comment: @rene I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @rene you're searching for HTTPS images, which don't need fixing.

Comment: I need coffee then ... sorry.

Comment: @muru I rechecked but there are simply no more links on http. All are replaced with https links as stated by Robert.

Comment: @rene If you believe that, I have got a bridge... The last time the query worked, we got these links: https://etherpad.net/p/au-img-cleanup You can check those which haven't been fixed already to see that there are still posts without HTTPS images (either being dead or HTTP-only). (on that etherpad, we're removing `http://` from the post links to mark them as fixed)