# Raw-Link titles not rendering properly in preview

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

When editing a question on Cryptography.SE I noticed that when using the full (adress-bar) link, the full (raw) link would also appear in the preview and when saved it would properly show the title.

Example (open in edit mode to see the raw link):

- [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only)

Observed behavior:

[image: Illustration]

Expected behavior:

[image: 2nd Illustration]

To clarify:

- The bug occurs for both HTTP and HTTPS links
- The bug occurs also (or especially?) for Same-Site-Links (ie MSE -> MSE or Crypto -> Crypto)
- I *do* use HTTPS Everywhere and Firefox on Windows (10), which seems to break stuff here on SE sometimes

Comment: Specifically, URLs with the `https` scheme. Guess it's another item to add to the transition list, heh

Comment: @TimStone actually, the original point where I discovered this was with `http` URLs. And indeed this bug also applies to `http` URLs (I just verified that)

Comment: @TimStone no, that's the first thing I checked when trying to reproduce. Any link isn't parsed, not only https links

Comment: @ShadowWizard Switching it to `http` here seems to [work fine for me though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnjd7.png)?

Comment: @TimStone are you talking about the protocol used to navigate MSE (I always use HTTPS there) or about the protocol embedded in the link?

Comment: @TimStone not here, it happens when you try to link to a question on different site, e.g. to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only) on Cryptography.SE as OP did, or from any other non MSE site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In a way inconsistent with [the 2a not applying in preview restriction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/108475#108475), or?

Comment: @SEJPM The protocol in the link; the only example I see in your edit history is a http -> https swap (and the http variant works for me), but maybe that's not the one you're referring to

Comment: @Tim oh, so it never worked? Might be, not 100% sure about that. If so you can write answer here quoting the restrictions, saying that links from main sites to other main sites are not parsed.

Comment: OK, so the issues I demonstrated here and on crypto _are_ links to other questions on the same site (ie crypto -> crypto and MSE -> MSE). They _do_ appear for me regardless of whether the link uses `http` or `https`. It _may_ have something to do with the fact that I use HTTPS Everywhere (which seems to break subtle details more often than not on SE it appears). The original crypto reference Q is [this one.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44300/23623) My edits on this Q was a HTTP -> HTTPS conversion (I encountered the bug pre- and post-edit) and here a HTTPS -> HTTP -> HTTPS test.

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, I see now @SEJPM. The API request is still using JSONP (whyyyyy?) and does so over HTTP exclusively, so the insecure request is blocked when you're browsing the site via HTTPS. Several simultaneous bugs here!