# HTTPS image conversion didn't work for .ico files

Tags: bug, images, community-user, ssl, scripts

In [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only), Step 3 said:

> After this is enabled, old posts that have HTTP images, accessible via HTTPS, will be edited accordingly. This will be an actual markdown change, attributed to the Community user, posts won't be bumped.

Today, I revisted an old post I'd made, which had images from HTTP URLs that were *part of StackExchange*, and found that the images were no longer displayed but instead replaced by text URLs.  I had to [edit the post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2525/revisions) manually to add an `s` after `http` and that worked just fine.

**This change should have been made automatically.** That it was not, indicates some bug or incompleteness in the script which adjusted image URLs. That bug may affect other posts too.

Comment: Probably ".ico" extension wasn't included in the script, only common image extensions. It's not too late, they can add this and re-run the script.

Comment: Whatever set of extensions is used in deciding what to not load and display the error message for, should match the script used for adaptation.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't jump to blaming the .ico until surveying other examples, to find a pattern of .ico files never getting changed and all other extensions getting changed.