# Non-HTTPS images are still served in some cases

Tags: bug, images, ssl, http

Regarding the announcement from last March, [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only), has there been a recent change to this policy?

Non-HTTPS images are being displayed on some posts. For example, from MathOverflow, see [Is there a way to get the closed form approximate result of ..](//mathoverflow.net/a/256376).

Comment: Nothing has changed. It's likely the rewrite just missed that post when the conversion took place, possibly because it uses `<IMG` and the replace wasn't case-insensitive or something.

Comment: Yeah, that does look like a bug with the rebake. AFAICT, those images *should've* been turned into links, but apparently they weren't.

Comment: Ps. [Apparently](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2010-12-01&EndDate=2099-01-01) there are 98 such missed posts on MO, most (but not all) of them from the same user who seems to be fond of uppercase `<IMG>` tags.

Comment: changed into bug, if this is resolved then please mark it so...

Comment: Confirmed, still an issue. [Example post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105681/tcp-send-queue-depth)

Comment: @Sonic any data how many such images are there? If dozens or even hundreds, we can edit manually, if thousands no choice but to re-run the script, case insensitive this time.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou Can't exactly say because the query times out. But I fixed a few instances on SO.

Comment: @animuson It seems the rewrite never took place on per-site metas, and so there are a lot of non-HTTPS images being served on per-site metas: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261626?StartDate=2010-01-01&EndDate=2012-01-01. Those all use standard Markdown for images, *not* things like capital `<IMG` tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to have been mostly fixed with the recent global re-rendering of most posts to CommonMark. All posts that were re-rendered as a result of the migration no longer exhibit this bug.

In the case of the one example I linked in the comments, the non-HTTPS image was previously showing in the revision history, but now it's only showing up as a link. Also, the query linked by Ilmari Karonen returns no results for most sites (as that checks the rendered HTML for a non-HTTPS image embed).

However, as the CommonMark migration post says, a small percentage of posts were not re-rendered, as they used potentially unsupported markup that could not be automatically edited out. This subset of posts is still affected by this bug. After some searching, I found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8867816/2157772).

In summary, this bug has been fixed in the rendering engine, as it no longer renders insecure images when it was updated to the CommonMark specification. However, the posts that weren't re-rendered with the updated renderer can still serve non-HTTPS images.

---

**Update:** After [querying this across all network sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261626?StartDate=2008-01-01&EndDate=2010-01-01) (except Stack Overflow due to its size), it seems the scope of this bug is a bit bigger than what I had thought before. It looks like the re-bake of non-HTTPS images into plain links never took place on per-site metas, and so there are a *lot* of per-site meta posts that serve non-HTTPS images. Those posts all use standard Markdown markup for images, so it's not the same (rare) issue encountered on main Q&A sites where there was a capital `<IMG` tag.

(Note: if you run the query above, only search for one year at a time - longer periods may make it time out.)