# Community should add HTTPS to Chat links

Tags: feature-request, community-user, ssl

Community changed all links to `stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com` to HTTPS a while ago. However, it seems to have not done this to links to `chat.stackexchange.com`, as seen [in this search](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackexchange.com), [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackexchange.com), and [this search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackexchange.com).

I don't want to manually edit and bump a bunch of old posts, so could the Community user be programmed to do it like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/399694)?